# How to manually add Content to a Matrix-Row with SafeCracker

Tags: matrix, safecracker

I need to use SafeCracker to publish a new entry into a Channel whose Custom-Field-Group exists of only one field — which is a quite large Matrix-field. (Matrix -> pixel&tonic Fieldtype)

The code look like this (but with much more fields)

```
{exp:safecracker channel='mychannel' return='success' include_jquery='no' datepicker='no'
…
<input type="hidden" name="title" class="title" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="mychannel-field0" class="field0" value="" />
…
{/exp:safecracker}
```

The fields will get filled through a JavaScript-Datafetcher.

My Matrix-Field is named `{mychannel-entry}` and the first cell is named `mychannel-field0` etc.

How can I tell my form to input the values of my hidden fields into the first/new Row-Cells of a new entry to my channel?

Note: This form only adds new entries, no editing-functions required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I haven't been able to test this, but you *should* be able to just manually build your form like so:

```
{exp:safecracker channel='mychannel' return='success' include_jquery='no' datepicker='no'}
  <input type="hidden" name="mychannel-entry[row_order][]" value="row_new_0" />
  <input type="text" name="mychannel-entry[row_new_0][col_id_1]" />
  <input type="text" name="mychannel-entry[row_new_0][col_id_2]" />
  <input type="text" name="mychannel-entry[row_new_0][col_id_]" />
{exp:safecracker}
```

<strike>I've assumed above that your full column name in your matrix settings is `mychannel-fieldn`. Is that correct?</strike> Edit, the previous, struck through line was incorrect.

Where `col_id_n` is the column_id of the column in your matrix field - nb this is not the same as the column name - use firebug/dev tools to figure this out as suggested in the blog post linked in the other answer to this qn.

NB. Taken from a [similar question in P&T's support forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/matrix_and_safecracker%5C).

Comment: THX! this works!

Answer (score 6):

I've done this before - I spoke with Marcus Neto about it and sent him the code for it which he blogged about [here](http://marcusneto.com/blog/article/breaking_up_a_matrix_field_for_use_in_a_safecracker_form)

This should give you enough information to do what you need I think.

Comment: thx for the reference to the blog-post! that's a nice reference incl. the «add»- and «remove»-functionality! THX! Since Tom was 3 Minutes faster, I have to give him the «Accept Answer» — I hope you don't mind ;-)

Comment: Interesting why you'd give him the accept answer considering it doesn't actually answer your question and he just references my post - but it's entirely up to you! :)

Comment: @madebyhippo I think it does precisely answer the OPs question - I actually got my answer from the P&T support forum post I linked to, then referenced the (different) post you linked (with credit) to correct an error I made when generalising from the P&T post to the OP's use case. You essentially posted the same answer but as a link to a different external resource a few minutes after my original post - I wasn't trying to "jump" your answer, just wanted to provide the most correct info **on this site** that I could.

Comment: @madebyhippo have clarified my previous edit. if that makes sense. Meta!

Comment: Thanks for that link Carl! That was exactly what I needed!