# Safecracker and Channel Relationships

Tags: safecracker

I'm using Safecracker to edit entries for the Channel Foo.

Suppose I have another Channel Images which has a filename field and a relationship field that points to Channel Foo.

Essentially, a Channel Foo entry can have 0 or more "images"(1-to-many)

Now when I am editing entries, I may want to add new images to a Channel Foo entry.

Is there a way to do it in Safecracker?

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not using a Matrix field for your images?

Comment: @pvledoux It is because I want to use my own custom markup for displaying the images. Matrix only displays predefined markup.

Comment: Actually you can, see this post: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/210/how-to-manually-add-content-to-a-matrix-row-with-safecracker/213#213

Comment: This is what I was referring to in comments on my answer. My recommendation to use AJAX is to enable the ability to add fields within your Safecracker form, and create corresponding entries on the backend, fetching the new IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have a Playa field in Foo that allows you to choose multiple Images entries? (Instead of relating Foo to Images)

Comment: I'm trying to do this in SafeCracker, not EE's CP.

Comment: You can use Playa fields in Safecracker. There's just a limit to how much you can style them. You can also use AJAX to interact directly with the Matrix database table and use Matrix to add/remove multiple entries to your Foo entry. But I think you need to shift the 1:many relationship onto Foo.